# Como listar todos os followers de um perfil do usuário usando API do Github?

Tags: react, api, github, axios

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em ReactJS que deveria me retornar uma lista com todos os seguidores de um usuário. No entanto, em um usuário com mais de 100 seguidores, meu código  retorna apenas uma array com, no máximo, 30 seguidores. Como faço pra listar todos eles e não apenas 30?

OBS: Estou usando ReactJS e Axios

```
const getUserData = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  client.get(`/${loginValue}`)
  .then(response => {
    ctx.setUserData(response.data);
    nav('user');
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
  
  client.get(`/${loginValue}/followers`)
   .then(response => {
     ctx.setFollowersList(response.data)
     console.log(response.data) //Retorna apenas 30 seguidores
  })  
}
```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0):

Olhando a documentação da API do GitHub, podemos ver que essa requisição possui um parametro que define quantos usuários vão ser retornados por página. Esse limite é 30 por padrão, mas pode ser alterado para até 100.

O nome do parâmetro é `per_page`, então basta passar ele na sua requisição que você receberá até 100 usuários na resposta.

```js
// Retorna 100 seguidores.
client.get(`/${loginValue}/followers`, { params: { per_page: 100 } })
```

Caso você queira continuar recebendo 30 usuários por página, mas das outras páginas, basta passar o parâmetro `page`.

```js
// Retorna os próximos 30 seguidores.
client.get(`/${loginValue}/followers`, { params: { page: 1 } })
```

Link da documentação: https://docs.github.com/pt/rest/users/followers